# finite state transducer where concatenation of all UIO sequences is shorter than its shortest distinguishing sequence?

Tags: finite-automata

Is there a finite state transducer which has a set of Unique Input/Output sequences such that, when the UIO sequences are concatenated together, the resulting string is shorter than its shortest preset distinguishing sequence, supposing that the finite state transducer has a preset distinguishing sequence?

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "Unique Input/Output sequences"?  What is a "preset distinguishing sequence"?  Can you edit the question to make it self-contained, and define all terms?  2. What are your thoughts?  What have you tried so far?